# Checking if Thumbnail and Full Image are a match in PHP

Tags: php, compare

I have a large database with images. Problem is, quite some images have the wrong thumbnail, so I need to confirm that they match.

I want to compare the thumbnail and full size image with each other, and come up with a percentage that they match.

The thumbnails & full images do not have exactly the same dimensions.

The full images are PNG's with transparent backgrounds, and the thumbnails have a grey/white grid as a background.

What is the best way to see if a thumbnail & full image match?

Example of how a full image & thumbnail look.

[image]

I found & tried: https://github.com/kennethrapp/phasher but this gets thrown off by the grid background in the thumbnails.

Comment: Good question. If you're unable to find a suitable solution, you could run through the originals and recreate the thumbnails and their links.

Comment: Creating new thumbs isn't an option unfortunately. It's a bit of a strange situation, but I really need a way to compare images.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had nearly the same problem and my solution was that I compare the timestamp of the full size image with the one of the thumb. If the thumb is older, then a new full size image was uploaded and my system creates a new thumb (and also clears the according cache).

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option in my case.

Comment: Well, okay, was just a try ;-)